# How to isolate a COM component .Net

Tags: .net, winforms, com, registry, clickonce

I develop a windows form application using Interop.bpac.dll provided by brother.
I tried to deploy the project using clickonce and a setup project but I can't manage to put the application working on other machine. I always get "Cannot create activex component". I think the problem is that the setup process don't register the COM component, but I don't know how to solve this. I've tried everything.

I know that we can isolate a COM component but I can't find the property I keep seeing on the internet.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

I've found the problem.  What you need to do is

```
1. Select the deployment project in Solution Explorer.

2. On the Project menu, point to Add, and then click Merge Module.

3. Select the the module C:\Program Files\Brother bPAC3 SDK\Redist\bPAC3.msm that is created when you install the SDK
```

Is working :)

Comment: Reg-free COM doesn't solve this problem, you still need to have the COM component properly deployed to that machine.  You will get no help from Brother to tell you exactly what DLLs are required, they will tell you to simply run the component's installer.  Good advice.

Comment: I've installed the SDK in my computer so everything works here. But on client's machine doesn't. Brother doesn't have any documentation regarding this. I suspect if I register this DLL on the client's machine the program will work.

Comment: I've found the problem.  What you need to do is 


    1. Select the deployment project in Solution Explorer.

    2. On the Project menu, point to Add, and then click Merge Module.

    3. Select the the module C:\Program Files\Brother bPAC3 SDK\Redist\bPAC3.msm that is created when you install the SDK


Is working :)

Comment: @cristelo, make that an answer - you can answer your own questions, and in ths case you should.

Comment: I'm a new user so I need to wait 8 hours. 2 hours now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.  What you need to do is

```
1. Select the deployment project in Solution Explorer.

2. On the Project menu, point to Add, and then click Merge Module.

3. Select the the module C:\Program Files\Brother bPAC3 SDK\Redist\bPAC3.msm that is created when you install the SDK
```

Is working :)